# Gradle can't find dependency in private nexus repo

Tags: gradle, nexus

I'm having trouble getting gradle to find a dependency I put in my private nexus repo.  The dependency is in maven, but I can't seem to get it to find it there either.  I did get it into my nexus repo and the location is http://nexus.hq.chris.com/content/repositories/emoji4j/

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':business:compile'.
> Could not find com.kcthota:emoji4j:6.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
      http://nexus.hq.chris.com/content/groups/public/com/kcthota/emoji4j/6.0/emoji4j-6.0.pom
      http://nexus.hq.chris.com/content/groups/public/com/kcthota/emoji4j/6.0/emoji4j-6.0.jar
      file:/Users/chris/.m2/repository/com/kcthota/emoji4j/6.0/emoji4j-6.0.pom
      file:/Users/chris/.m2/repository/com/kcthota/emoji4j/6.0/emoji4j-6.0.jar
  Required by:
```

Build.gradle snipet

```
dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.kcthota/emoji4j
    compile group: 'com.kcthota', name: 'emoji4j', version: '6.0'
}



buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://nexus.hq.chris.com/content/groups/public/"
        }
        maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/" }
        maven { url "http://nexus.hq.chris.com/content/repositories/emoji4j/" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.54'
    }
}
```

Anyone know how I can get gradle to look in both http://nexus.hq.chris.com/content/groups/public/ and http://nexus.hq.chris.com/content/repositories/emoji4j/ for all my dependencies?  I need the http://nexus.hq.chris.com/content/groups/public/ location for other dependencies.  I tried adding it in there but I only have read access to that repo.

Another acceptable solution would be to get gradle to look in both http://nexus.hq.chris.com/content/groups/public/ and maven central for it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you may be confusing dependencies for your [build script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies) and [application dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html).

You've configured your build script repositories, but you'll need to also configure your application repositories as well:

```
// build.gradle

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://nexus.hq.chris.com/content/groups/public/"
    }
    maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/" }
    maven { url "http://nexus.hq.chris.com/content/repositories/emoji4j/" }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: I'm confused what you recommend I do differently

Comment: @Chellmich put the repositories block outside of the buildscript block as well. The buildscript repositories are only for plugins